# Shopify App development

Tags: shopify

I am a Joomla and WordPress developer. Now I want to learn shopify store. I am planning to develop an app to extend the shop functionality and seeing that app on market store(Like WordPress market store).

Till now I couldn't understand how I can develop my own custom app. No documentation was found with code examples. Can any one help ?

Comment: shopify documentation give you examples and code of how to build apps:   [https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth](https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/oauth)  , [https://docs.shopify.com/api/libraries/full-listing](https://docs.shopify.com/api/libraries/full-listing)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you must be familiar with is OAuth (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) it is important to understand the API calls to shopify endpoints, the second thing you must know is about RESTFul, specifically the Shopify's RESTFul API (https://help.shopify.com/api/reference), knowing these points, you will be able to develope any app to extend shopify's functionality. Hope this help.